# Cannot find "signed" APK file exported by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have built an application using Eclipse IDE and then when I try to "Export Signed application" - I fill out the forms and create keys and other things that I'm supposed to do. But I cannot find the APK file at the destination I specify. I know that there's an APK file under bin but it's not zipaligned.

Same thing with Zipalign when I specify the output file, I cannot see the output file although it says "Verification successful". I have tried running Eclipse under Administrator mode but doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: How are you specifying the destination? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: @auspicious99 I have used the standard wizard provided by Eclipse. Only apk I can find is in bin :(

Comment: Check in the location where your keystore resides.

Comment: What platform are you running eclipse on? @VikramV it shouldn't matter where the keystore resides. On most platforms that I know of, the wizard will let you choose where the exported apk is saved. Then, it should be there at the end of the whole process.